# IntelliSense/JSDoc @param = @return, a.k.a. how do I document wrapper functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

I have a function which takes in another function as an argument, does *something* to that function-argument, and then returns that same function-argument (or at least returns a function with the exact same signature to it)

```js
/**
 * The param and return should be the same (as far as JSDoc is concerned)!
 * @param {Function} fnToWrap
 * @returns {fnToWrap}
 */
function wrapperFunction(fnToWrap) {
    // Does something...
    return fnToWrap;
}
```

However, as you can see from my comments in the following...

```js
/**
 * IntelliSense detects this...
 * @param paramA 
 * @returns 
 */
var arbitraryFn = function(paramA) {
    return paramA * 2;
}


// But NOT this!!!
var wrappedArbitraryFn = wrapperFunction(arbitraryFn);
```

... IntelliSense will autocomplete when calling `arbitraryFn()` but not `wrappedArbitraryFn()`.

Is there any way to get IntelliSense to *dynamically* autocomplete my wrapped functions with the same signature as their unwrapped counterparts, i.e. *without* having to explicitly re-document every newly-wrapped function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm revisiting this again as I now have a (near-)perfect solution for my use-case. The reality is IntelliSense is *far* more TypeScript than it is standard JSDoc. As it turns out, you can leverage the `@template` tag to solve the above, and as far as I've seen, *anything I can accomplish in TypeScript I can also accomplish in JavaScript IntelliSense*:

**The New Wrapper Function**

```
/**
 * The param and return should be the same (as far as JSDoc is concerned)!
 * @template {Function} T
 * @param {T} fnToWrap
 * @returns {T}
 */
 function wrapperFunction(fnToWrap) {
    // Does something...
    return fnToWrap;
}
```

**Wrapping a Previously-Declared Function**

```
/**
 * IntelliSense detects this...
 * @param {Number} paramA 
 */
function previouslyDeclared(paramA) {
    return paramA * 2;
}

// And it also detects this!
var afterWrapping = wrapperFunction(previouslyDeclared);
```

**Wrapping an inline Function**

```
// And it also detects this!
var wrappedArbitraryFn = wrapperFunction(
    /**
     * IntelliSense detects this
     * @param {String} a 
     * @param {Number} b 
     * @param {Function} c 
     * @returns 
     */
    (a, b, c) => {
        return 22;
    }
);
```

Only downside for me is the inline is a bit ugly, imo, but it works. However, do note that **this may not be a valid solution for true/vanilla JSDoc**. This solution is great if, like me, you don't really use/care about JSDoc and you're really just here for the IntelliSense piece.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't *exactly* what I'm looking for, but after posting this question I did discover this method which isn't too bad:

```js
/**
 * @type {arbitraryFn}
 */
var wrappedArbitraryFn = wrapperFunction(arbitraryFn);
```

This works and isn't too tedious, however be aware of the following:

- This requires pre-defining the original function. In other words, I can't get this to work for functions declared inside the call to the wrapper function, e.g. this won't work for `var wrapped = wrapperFunction((a, b) => a + b)`
- **This will break** if you try to rename the function with the "Rename Symbol" command (F2) in Visual Studio Code **unless** you document the original function with an `@typedef`. Putting a `@typedef` every time might be fine, but I don't know if there are any side effects to that tag. Plus it's an extra step to remember, and one that doesn't have obvious/immediate consequences if you forget it

So I'm still very open to answers!

Answer (score 0):

@user3781737 solution worked for me, after 6+ hours of debugging.

If anyone is having trouble getting props suggestions to work on components with forwarded props ie: {...props} I have found this solution using JSdoc @type annotation. It requires you have access to the props of the component where you are forwarding the props to:

```
import React from 'react';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import { HeaderButton, HeaderButtonProps } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

/**
 * Used to wrap react-navigations default headerButton. 
 *
 * @type {React.FC<ButtonPropTypes & HeaderButtonProps>}
 */
const DefaultHeaderButton = props => {
    return (
        <HeaderButton 
            {...props} 
            IconComponent={MaterialCommunityIcons} 
            iconSize={30} 
            color={props.color || "#fff"}
        />
    );
};

DefaultHeaderButton.displayName = 'DefaultHeaderButton';
const ButtonPropTypes = {
    color: PropTypes.string
}
DefaultHeaderButton.propTypes = ButtonPropTypes;

export default DefaultHeaderButton;
```

Edit: I realized this is only necessary if the propTypes are a typescript interface while using javascript. In most cases you can just spread the original item's propTypes into your custom propTypes.